# Path of accelerating electron in magnetic field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, electric-fields

Consider an electron that is gaining in speed, whilst also inside a magnetic field. In particular, consider the following diagram.

> Electrons are emitted from a cathode C and are accelerated by the
> potential difference V between the cathode and the slit S1. The shaded region is a magnetic field going into the page.

[image]

Can electrons actually get from C to ${S_1}$? The reason I am doubtful is because if we consider the following:
$$F_c = F_B$$
$$\frac{mv^2}{r} = qvB$$
$$r = \frac{mv}{qB} $$

As the electron is getting faster and faster, then the radius will have to be increasing too. To get to S1, it needs to follow the arc of the circle - which means it needs the same velocity as the electron has after S1.

But because the electron is accelerating, then at C they are really slow - so I don't think they can follow the right path to get to S1. I think the question also assumes a magic semi circular electric field between C and S1.

How can I derive an equation that plots the path from C to S1? What does the path from C to S1 look like?

Comment: You are right,  with constant R, this is not possible. Usually the first acceleration is linear.